# How to export contenthash value for each output in Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have a fairly simple Webpack 4 configuration that generates several JS files with their own contenthashes.

An example for JS:

```
entry: {
        build: './public/js/main.dev.js',
        vueApp: './public/js/vueApp/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'
    },
```

Now, in order to use server-side rendering, I need to somehow export the current contenthash values from webpack after they are generated. Is there a clean way to achieve this? 
I have already tried generating a HTML file using html-webpack-plugin, but parsing additional HTML on each render doesn't seem like the most optimized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the closest thing I found to an answer is Webpack manifest plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin

It basically generates a manifest JSON file linking together the files with their hashed names, so it can be parsed on the server side before delivering the content.